# Copy apfs system partition to another mac

Tags: partition, apfs, migration

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) that has broken keyboard and battery, so I will need to send it to Apple Store for service. I have another MacBook Pro with similar specs but 1 TB of storage with a macOS system and a Windows 10 system. My current plan is to shrink the Windows 10 partition, connect the broken MBP to the other MBP in target disk mode, use asr to copy the macOS partition over, and I should be able to boot of the other MBP. Would this plan work? Will asr copy blocks that have information on them (fs/meta/data) or will it conduct a block-to-block copy, including free blocks? I want to minimize read as the SSD have a limited lifespan.

Comment: Which version of macOS is installed on the Mac to be serviced? What is asr? Also, the SSD limits are usually related to writes, not reads.

Comment: Having said that: Installing macOS on the "other" MBP first, and then using Migration Assistant to get applications and user data from the "to-be-serviced" Mac might be the better option.

Comment: I'm not sure that reading affects the lifespan of an SSD notably, does it?

Comment: @nohillside macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, same version. But that doesn't matter, because I'm not going to touch the system partition on the other mac.

Comment: @nohillside That take way longer than copying directly (installing a fresh system require around 20 minute, and bit-by-bit copying should take less than 10 minute, assuming 1GB/s sequential read/write, as advertised by Apple.

Comment: Also, Migration Assistant probably does not copy things I changed in system directories and root account files? Apple exclude things that they think no one will need but sometimes I do need them.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that only writing affects the lifespan, which will be the reason for another question about copying the system partition back after the repair.

Comment: Regarding asr, just read its manual page. It's short for "Apple Software Restore; copy volumes (e.g. from disk images)". It seems to be an official tool that Apple uses.

Comment: It would not be a block to block copy. I would recommend doing so from Recovery mode. You could use the Disk Utility to accomplish the copy. Use Windows to create a new formatted partition. Use macOS to reformat to APFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up copying the system over using the "Restore" function of Disk Utility, by connecting the serviced mac in Target Disk Mode to the other mac and restoring the macOS APFS container over to the Windows partition. This process is slower (300 MB/s) then the theoretical speed (1 GB/s) and it took twice as much time as I expect because there is a verification stage after the copying stage.

After copying the system, I successfully booted into my copied system on the other mac with no weird or unusual symptoms. I installed macOS again to eliminate potential problems due to changed hardware.